# pinning of MAX232

Tags: max232

I just want to ask if there is ever a connection between pin 2 and pin 3 of MAX232. I did a continuity test between those two pins. One of my MAX232 has shorted pin 2 and pin 3. My other IC does not have connection between those two. Now I am confused which of them is the correct one. Thank you.

Comment: I always used this pinning: http://sodoityourself.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/circuit_232.jpg and never had problems with it. As you can see pin 2 and pin 3 are not connected.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect if you try your continuity tester probes both ways round on the pins you will get different results. The pins are not shorted, they have different functions, and an internal protection diode in one direction.